# Match two column values from 2 data sets, then find associated values

Tags: excel

The issue I'm having was hard to title, and hard to search as well.

Here's some example data.

```
A   B           C       D   E           F

B1  04/14/16    746     B1  04/25/16    2
B1  04/15/16    180     B1  04/30/16    4
B1  04/16/16    494     B1  05/01/16    5
B1  04/17/16    726     B2  04/01/16    1
B1  04/18/16    206     B2  04/03/16    1
B1  04/19/16    22      B2  04/04/16    2
B1  04/20/16    193     B2  04/05/16    2
B1  04/21/16    739     B2  04/12/16    8
B1  04/22/16    926     B2  04/13/16    1
B1  04/23/16    748     B2  04/14/16    2
B1  04/24/16    830     B2  04/15/16    1
B1  04/25/16    272     B2  04/18/16    9
B1  04/26/16    0       B2  04/19/16    1
B1  04/27/16    0       B2  04/26/16    9
B1  04/28/16    0       B2  04/27/16    3
B1  04/29/16    0       B2  04/30/16    1
B1  04/30/16    685     B2  05/02/16    5
B1  05/01/16    770     B2  05/03/16    2
B1  05/02/16    701     B3  04/03/16    3
B1  05/03/16    181     B3  04/04/16    1
B2  04/01/16    77      B3  04/06/16    2
B2  04/02/16    182     B3  04/07/16    1
B2  04/03/16    53      B3  04/09/16    1
B2  04/04/16    32      B3  04/16/16    7
```

What I'm trying to do is check for matching A and D columns, as well as matching B and E columns. If the columns match I would like to take column F and divide by column C.

Also if there is no match for both A and B column values, then have return those values with a zero.

So for a match:

```
B1   04/25/16   =2/272
```

For a non-match:

```
B1   04/14/16   0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two INDEX/MATCH Function will do it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$24,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$1:$E$24=J2)*($D$1:$D$24=I2),),0))/INDEX($C$1:$C$24,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$B$24=J2)*($A$1:$A$24=I2),),0)),0)
```

This is an array formula, Full column references should be avoided as the calculation are exponential and will increase the calculation times.

If a more dynamic range is wanted then use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1E+99,F:F)),MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,F:F))=J2)*($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,F:F))=I2),),0))/INDEX($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C)),MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))=J2)*($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))=I2),),0)),0)
```

This will find the last cell with data and use that to set the extents of the range.  So now as the data grows or shrinks it will only look at the data and not iterate through any more or any less than what is needed to cover the entire data set.

[image]